# JQuery selector for table every row first column

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select every row's first column.But the first column maybe has 'rowspan' property.

So like this.

html:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">first1<td>
    <td>first2<td>
    <td>first3<td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>second2<td>
    <td>second3<td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>third1<td>
    <td>third2<td>
    <td>third3<td>
<tr>
```

I choose the first column, but I get those result.

```
$("tr td:first-child");

"<td rowspan="2">first1<td>,<td>second2<td>,<td>third1<td>"
```

expect result is

```
"<td rowspan="2">first1<td>,<td>third1<td>"
```

I want to get those columns to fixed columns for table left-right scroll.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the expected result? `"<td rowspan="2">first1<td>,<td>third1<td>"`?

Comment: What do you want to do with them? There would be a big difference between creating array of data vs adding a class

Comment: What's wrong with those results? `second2` is the first column of the second row.

Comment: I've changed the question description.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might get you started although there are numerous plugins available for doing what you want

```
var $rows = $('tr'), skipCount = 0;

var $cloneTable = $('<table>');
$rows.each(function () {
    var $row = $(this), $firstCell;
    var $newRow = $('<tr>');
    if (!skipCount) {
        $firstCell = $row.find('td').first();
        $newCell =$firstCell.clone().height($firstCell.height());        
        $newRow.append($newCell);
        var rowSpan = +$firstCell.attr('rowspan');
        if (rowSpan) {
            skipCount = rowSpan-1;
        }
    } else {
        skipCount--;
    }
    $cloneTable.append($newRow);

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/csowvkdb/)**</kbd>

Comment: At first I wanted to use the selector to complete it.Now this is the only way to implement it.Thank you.